# Only every-other horizontal grid line is printing in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

Even though the grid lines (which I have set to print) show up correctly in the print preview screen, the print comes out with EVERY-OTHER horizontal line printed. This is in the regular workbook, row height 16, Excel 2016, Windows 10.

Comment: From the description, people will only be able to guess at possibilities.  Are all settings at the default values?  Are you printing "full size" (vs. adjusting page breaks to fit more on a page)?  Can you scan a sample page (or snap a picture of one), stick that on an image sharing site like imgur.com, and add a link to it?

Comment: Try printing to `PDF` first. If the issue persists, the issue is with Excel - otherwise could be something else too

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your printer. Try to convert your sheet to pdf first and print that as @Prasanna has already adviced.

Comment: Grid lines are printed as single-pixel grey lines. These may not print correctly on some printers. What happens if you change row height? What happens if you give the cells black borders, do they print correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It will print every other line if your print quality is in draft mode.
In Excel, go to

> File -> Page-up -> Print quality -> Select "normal or best".

I'm assuming you already checked off print gridlines.